# Google Cloud Vision API "Bad image data" error

Tags: api, vision

I'm using google cloud vision API trying to detect text from maps. The image size I'm processing is less than 20MB and it is stored in cloud storage. When I run the document_text_detection API, some of the images lead to the following error (some were processed successfully)

> Something went wrong with the Vision API:code: 3 
>   message: "Bad image data"

I wonder what could be the reason? I tried convert the jpeg file to png format and then convert back. The image that is problematic is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17-_Oqoj0iOGQBowzzV8RS0e1O8fIQakt/view?usp=sharing).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like converting **jpg** files to **png** format could do the trick. The only problem is that the png file might be too big for the API to accept. In this case, I managed to reduced the image size by either lowering the image quality or shrink the image to smaller width and height.

Comment: I definitely used `DetectDocumentText` passing jpg files lots of times - and I got the text extracted, so this sounds ungrounded.

Answer (score 2):

Another situation that can cause the "Bad image data" error is using the "Authenticated URL" instead of the URI or the "Public URL" of the resource. Don't know why that happens, just ran across it exploring the [Using API Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart) tutorial of the Cloud Vision API.

Likely unrelated to your situation, posting this for the benefit of those who hit the same problem and end up here after searching for a solution.

Comment: So bizarre. Google implies that you can even use `gs://<bucket>/<path>` from their [docs on the client](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/labels#detect_labels_in_a_remote_image). However I get "bad image data" when I try this way.